# comparing range of values with another range of values mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (shrewd_db.threshold) in MySQL database where I have executed following code

```
select  id_indicator, id_threshold, activation_begin_value, activation_end_value 
from shrewd_db.threshold
where active =1
group by id_indicator, id_threshold;
```

My output is as follows:

```
 id_indicator   id_threshold    activation_begin_value  activation_end_value 

   2                5                   4                 58
   2                6                   3                  3
   2                7                   1                  2
   2                8                   0                  0
   4               13                   0                4.5
   4               15                 4.1                5.5
   4               16                5.51                  6
   4               17                6.01                100
```

Each id_indicator has four range of id_threshold.

Now for a data validation check I need to find out each indicator id_threshold (activation_begin_value and  activation_end_value) not fall into another threshold.

My desired output should be like:

```
 id_indicator   id_threshold    activation_begin_value  activation_end_value 


   4               13                   0                4.5
   4               15                 4.1                5.5
```

where id_indicator (4) two id_threshold(13,15) values falls each other. Mainly identify threshold must not overlap

Comment: `where id_indicator (4) two id_threshold(13,15) values falls each other ` => This doesn't make sense to. Can you elaborate why do you need only these 2 rows in output and not any other rows?

Comment: example id indicator 4 has value 4.2, if I need to find out value 4.2 fall into which threshold my out put giving me above result which fall in to threshold 13 and 15. generally each threshold should have unique range of value that is why for data validation check I need to find all those anomalies and resolve the threshold problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean that activation periods must not overlap, right?

Then a query checking this would look as follows:

```
select distinct t1.* from threshold t1, threshold t2 where
  t1.id_indicator = t2.id_indicator and
  t1.id_threshold <> t2.id_threshold and
    (  t1.activation_begin_value BETWEEN t2.activation_begin_value and 
       t2.activation_end_value
    OR t1.activation_end_value BETWEEN t2.activation_begin_value and 
       t2.activation_end_value
    )
```

The query is tested with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE threshold
    (`id_indicator` int, `id_threshold` int, `activation_begin_value` numeric(5,2), `activation_end_value` numeric(5,2))
;

INSERT INTO threshold
    (`id_indicator`, `id_threshold`, `activation_begin_value`, `activation_end_value`)
VALUES
    (2, 5, 4, 58),
    (2, 6, 3, 3),
    (2, 7, 1, 2),
    (2, 8, 0, 0),
    (4, 13, 0, 4.5),
    (4, 15, 4.1, 5.5),
    (4, 16, 5.51, 6),
    (4, 17, 6.01, 100)
;
```

And yields the following results:

```
id_indicator|id_threshold|activation_begin_value | activation_end_value
------------|------------|-----------------------|---------------------
           4|          15|                    4.1|                  5.5
           4|          13|                      0|                  4.5
```

Comment: i am getting an error while running your code in "OR" area

Comment: hm - I've actually tested the query (see edited answer). Maybe your schema is different from the one that I derived from your sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Your given Query - for which you are getting output - must be throwing error

It cab be -
    select  id_indicator, id_threshold, min(activation_begin_value), 
    Max      (activation_end_value) 
    from shrewd_db.threshold
    where active =1
    group by id_indicator, id_threshold;

If you correct this and take this output in some temp table and then write Self Join based activation_begin_value ,  activation_end_value I think you may get your result.

Else write cursor on the above output and compare row by row...if it's one time job and Performance is not issue..

Comment: could you help me how to write cursor because it is one time code for data validation and performance is not going to be an issue